# Android: DrawRect Not getting Displayed on Canvas of HD phones

Tags: android, drawrect

Lately I have developed the Board Game ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pradhan.manoj.CoinStack ). It is working fine in all Android powered devices except few phones those are having HD display including Micromax Canvas HD and Samsung Galaxy Grand. I have been finding difficulty in figuring out what I have been doing wrong. Below is an extract from the code...

```
  rectPaint = new Paint();
  rectPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
  rectPaint.setDither(true);
  rectPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  rectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  rectPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
  rectPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

  //CurrentX, CurrentY are calculated dynamically

  rectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
  canvas.drawRect(currentX,currentY,currentX+cellWidth,currentY-cellHeight,rectPaint);
  rectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  rectPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  canvas.drawRect(currentX,currentY,currentX+cellWidth,currentY-cellHeight,rectPaint);
```

Your expert advice/suggestion to nail down this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: same problem. if i draw circle it's fine, but not works with rect.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution: check the difference of the coordinates - it should not be negative.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this, but this seems to be correct. In older APIs, it is possible to draw from high to low, on new APIs, the object doesn't draw.

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with the same problem.

For example older APIs drawn current code

```
Rect r1 = new Rect(631 , 576 , 702, 283 );
canvas.drawRect(r1,paintP);
```

But new API is not drawing anything

To fix it

```
Right coordinates must be greater the left
Bottom coordinates must be greater the top
```

It will be drawn

```
Rect r1 = new Rect(631 ,  283 , 702, 576 );
canvas.drawRect(r1,paintP);
```